# Зацикливание обработки исключений

Tags: c++, .net, юнит-тесты, отладка, c++-cli

Столкнулся с очень необычной проблемой. Причем что интересно, происходит она только в одном случае, когда происходит отладка юнит тестов (если запустить этот код ВНЕ цикла отладки юнит теста, то все в порядке - все работает как ожидается).

У меня есть следующий c++/cli код:

```
MngdClass^ create_mngd_obj()
{
    try
    {
        native_class.build_object(); 
        return gcnew MngdClass(native_class.get_object());
    }
    catch (const NativeException& e)
    {
        int i = 0;
    }
}
```

вот нативный код, который выбрасывает исключение (стоит обратить внимание, что он находится в отдельной нативной c++ библиотеке):

```
struct NativeException
{
    const std::string message;
    NativeException(const std::string& message_) : message(message_)
    {
    }
};

void NativeClass()
{
    throw NativeException("O la la");
}
```

Так вот, если попытаться продебажить этот код в юнит тестах, произойдет зацикливание. А именно, будет выполняться такая последовательность с выбросами исключений (сам не понимаю, почему раскрутки стэка не происходит):

```
 native_class.build_object(); 
 native_class.get_object();
```

Если же код отлаживать не в юнит тестах, все происходит нормально. Выбрасывается исключение которое благополучно отлавливается обработчиком

Answer (score 1):

Возможно кому-нибудь поможет. В настройках проекта для unit test'ов выставил `enable native code debugging` и `allow unsafe code`. Пока не понимаю, как это смогло помочь, буду разбираться